# Уничтожение экземпляра RecyclerView.Adapter, хотя ссылка на него была сохранена

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Есть фрагмент, которому я поставил retainInstance = true. Внутри фрагмента есть RecyclerView. В одно поле фрагмента я сохраняю состояние layoutManager-а, в другом - адаптер. После клика по элементу списка фрагмент открепляется, показывается другой. При клике назад снова показываю фрагмент с RecyclerView, поле с состоянием менеджера в порядке, а вот адаптер внезапно становится null, но его сеттер не вызывался.

Итого имеем фрагмент, который точно не пересоздавался и точно сохраняет все свои поля, кроме одного - адаптера. Как адаптер может быть потерян? я не использую WeakReference, разные области видимости поля не меняют дела... Есть предположение, что RecyclerView при уничтожении каким-то образом забирает с собой адаптер, но как это возможно не понимаю

Comment: Покажите код фрагмента с RV.

Comment: Нужен код вашего фрагмента. Очень трудно понять, что у вас происходит